# Declare SQL result as variable

Tags: c#, sql, variables, global

I need to send the ID of a logged in user to multiple windows forms but can't figure it out. How can I call the variable on multiple forms?

```
private void btnUpdate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
using(var con = new SqlConnection("connectionstring"))
{
 var query = "SELECT TOP 1 ID FROM users WHERE username = @username AND password = @password";
 // Build a command to execute your query
 using(var cmd = new SqlCommand(con,query))
 {
      // Open connection
      con.Open();
      // Add your parameters
      cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", txtUsername.Text);
      cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", txtPassword.Text);

      // Get ID
      var sqlid = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar());
 }
}
```

Ive been stumped for hours and can't proceed

Comment: Move your code to a method in a separate class, Have this method receives two parameters for user name and password. Your method should return the `sqlid`. Then you can use the method in multiple places.

Comment: You could make the variable a class-level field -- or better yet, a property -- instead of a local method variable, and set its access modifier so it is accessible to other classes (i.e. other "forms").

Answer (score 0):

> How can I call the variable on multiple forms?

Take the code out of your button click event.  Put it in a class within a shared library that can be accessed by multiple forms.

You should also create a `User` class (and a `UserRepository`) that you pass around instead of just an ID with no context.

Answer (score 0):

This is what D Stanley was talking about.

The User data-structure

```
public class MyUser
{
    public int ID;
    public string UserName;
    public MyUser(int id, string userName)
    {
        ID = id;
        UserName = userName;
    }
}
```

The database interface class

```
public class UserContext
{
    private ConnectionString = ""

    // 1st constructor you pass in connection string.
    public UserContext(string connectionString)
    {
        ConnectionString = connectionString;
    }

    // 2nd constructor you use the one in the web.config file.
    public UserContext()
    {
        ConnectionString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["connectionStringName"].ConnectionString;
    }

    public int GetUserID(string userName, string password)
    {
        // declare the result variable.
        MyUser result

        using(var con = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString))
        {

            var query = "SELECT TOP 1 ID FROM users WHERE username = @username AND password = @password";
            // Build a command to execute your query
             using(var cmd = new SqlCommand(con,query))
             {
                  // Open connection
                  con.Open();
                  // Add your parameters
                  cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(userName);
                  cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(password);

                  // Get ID
                  var sqlid = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar());
                  result = new MyUser(sqlid, userName);

             }
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

Now all you have to do is create a database context object and pass in properties.

```
private void btnUpdate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // database context.
    UserContext UC  = new UserContext();

    // Get user.
    MyUser currentUser = UC.GetUserID(txtUserName.Text, txtPassword.Text);

    // now you can access userid from the User data-structure object.
    var id = currentUser.ID; 
}
```